# Find websites of nearby restaurants in GoogleMaps API using Python

Tags: python, google-maps

The following code finds restaurants near Trafalgar Square in London:

```
import googlemaps

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='API_KEY')

# Geocoding an address
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('Trafalgar Square, London, United Kingdom')

# Look up nearby places
places_result = gmaps.places_nearby(location=geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location'], radius=500, type='restaurant')

for place in places_result['results']:
    print(place['name'])
```

However, I would like to get their websites, but I don't find any field such as `place['website']`?

Comment: From looking at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-data-fields#basic) I would assume you can use `place["URL"]`

Comment: The only provided fields are `['business_status', 'geometry', 'icon', 'icon_background_color', 'icon_mask_base_uri', 'name', 'opening_hours', 'photos', 'place_id', 'plus_code', 'rating', 'reference', 'scope', 'types', 'user_ratings_total', 'vicinity']`.

Comment: Then you probably need to use another or an additional endpoint. I would refer to the documentation for that

Comment: The endpoint `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.757870,-73.985070&radius=500&type=restaurant&fields=name,website&key=<API_KEY>` gives me the same result. Still no URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the endpoint you used each result will come with a `place_id` parameter. Using this `place_id` you can hit the [place details endpoint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details)

The URL looks like this and from what I've seen in the documentation there will be a website field included.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJi6C1MxquEmsR9-c-3O48ykI`